# Filter array of hashes and modify duplicates in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, filter, hash

I want to filter a params[] array of hashes in Ruby depending some content conditions.
I had look at some other discussions but the needs are different.

My array example:

```
{"id"=>"f00b5b20-0250-4e0d-8a05-c70905030a32", "optimized_nickname"=>"Grand Vin", "optimized_country_id"=>"1", "season_id"=>"a9840059-cc91-47aa-9098-4bf8a45655e7", "verified_status"=>"1"}
{"id"=>"8ee93dc5-abd3-4cdd-ad20-29fcf1168a66", "optimized_nickname"=>"Grand Vin 2", "optimized_country_id"=>"1", "season_id"=>"8ee93dc5-abd3-4cdd-ad20-29fcf1168a66", "verified_status"=>"1"}
{"id"=>"f00b5b20-0250-4e0d-8a05-c70905030a32", "optimized_nickname"=>"Grand Vin 3", "optimized_country_id"=>"1", "season_id"=>"f00b5b20-0250-4e0d-8a05-c70905030a32", "verified_status"=>"1"}
{"id"=>"f00b5b20-0250-4e0d-8a05-c70905030a32", "optimized_nickname"=>"Grand Vin", "optimized_country_id"=>"1", "season_id"=>"f00b5b20-0250-4e0d-8a05-c70905030a32", "verified_status"=>"1"}
```

The filtering conditions:

- when the **id** field is the same as another hash
- and the fields **optimized_nickname** and **optimized_country_id** have not the same values
- **don't touch** to the first hash responding to these 2 conditions
- modify all other hashes responding to these 2 conditions: set their **verified_status** field to 0 except if the previous hash has already `verified_status=0`

What I would like to obtain for this use case:

```
{"id"=>"f00b5b20-0250-4e0d-8a05-c70905030a32", "optimized_nickname"=>"Grand Vin", "optimized_country_id"=>"1", "season_id"=>"a9840059-cc91-47aa-9098-4bf8a45655e7", "verified_status"=>"1"}
{"id"=>"8ee93dc5-abd3-4cdd-ad20-29fcf1168a66", "optimized_nickname"=>"Grand Vin 2", "optimized_country_id"=>"1", "season_id"=>"8ee93dc5-abd3-4cdd-ad20-29fcf1168a66", "verified_status"=>"1"}
{"id"=>"f00b5b20-0250-4e0d-8a05-c70905030a32", "optimized_nickname"=>"Grand Vin 3", "optimized_country_id"=>"1", "season_id"=>"f00b5b20-0250-4e0d-8a05-c70905030a32", "verified_status"=>"0"}
{"id"=>"f00b5b20-0250-4e0d-8a05-c70905030a32", "optimized_nickname"=>"Grand Vin", "optimized_country_id"=>"1", "season_id"=>"f00b5b20-0250-4e0d-8a05-c70905030a32", "verified_status"=>"1"}
```

In the third hash, the **verified_status** field has been set to 0 because its values are different from the first hash (as they have the same id).

I think I need to use .map or .select, but don't know how to check values.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you compare first record with second, then second with third etc? Or you have one record from outside of `params` and you compare it with all records from `params`?

Comment: I want to compare the records on the uniq params array, one to one.

Comment: "...and the fields optimized_nickname and optimized_country_id have not the same values".  Do you mean "optimized_nickname OR optimized_country_id"?

Comment: Yes Michael. If at least 1 of the 2 is different from other hashes with same id.

Comment: You need to at least break down your problem with some sample code that shows the logic you're trying to represent. Even if it's not the whole hash, you really need to demonstrate what you've tried and any errors or incorrect output that shows why that isn't working for you. https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Answer (score 0):

If your hashes were in an array named 'list', you could simply scan the array and collect items by id to compare and update subsequent items in place.

```
first_items_by_id = Hash.new

list.each do |item|
    prev = first_items_by_id[item["id"]]
    item["verified_status"] = "0" if prev and ((item["optimized_nickname"] != prev["optimized_nickname"]) || (item["optimized_country_id"] != prev["optimized_country_id"]))
    first_items_by_id[item["id"]] = item if prev.nil?
end
```